# Random Page Cost and Planning

Tags: sql, optimization, postgresql

A query (see below) that extracts climate data from weather stations within a given radius of a city using the dates for which those weather stations actually have data. The query uses the table's only index, rather effectively:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX measurement_001_stc_idx
  ON climate.measurement_001
  USING btree
  (station_id, taken, category_id);
```

Reducing the server's configuration value for [`random_page_cost`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/runtime-config-query.html) from 2.0 to 1.1 had a massive performance improvement for the given range (nearly an order of magnitude) because it suggested to PostgreSQL that it should use the index. While the results now return in 5 seconds (down from ~85 seconds), problematic lines remain. Bumping the query's end date by a single year causes a full table scan:

```
sc.taken_start >= '1900-01-01'::date AND
sc.taken_end <= '1997-12-31'::date AND
```

How do I persuade PostgreSQL to use the indexes regardless of years between the two dates? (A full table scan against 43 million rows is probably not the best plan.) Find the EXPLAIN ANALYSE results below the query.

Thank you!

**Query**

```
  SELECT
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken) AS year,
    avg(m.amount) AS amount
  FROM
    climate.city c,
    climate.station s,
    climate.station_category sc,
    climate.measurement m
  WHERE
    c.id = 5182 AND
    earth_distance(
      ll_to_earth(c.latitude_decimal,c.longitude_decimal),
      ll_to_earth(s.latitude_decimal,s.longitude_decimal)) / 1000 <= 30 AND
    s.elevation BETWEEN 0 AND 3000 AND
    s.applicable = TRUE AND
    sc.station_id = s.id AND
    sc.category_id = 1 AND
    sc.taken_start >= '1900-01-01'::date AND
    sc.taken_end <= '1996-12-31'::date AND
    m.station_id = s.id AND
    m.taken BETWEEN sc.taken_start AND sc.taken_end AND
    m.category_id = sc.category_id
  GROUP BY
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken)
  ORDER BY
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken)
```

**1900 to 1996: Index**

```
"Sort  (cost=1348597.71..1348598.21 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=2268.929..2268.935 rows=92 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: (date_part('year'::text, (m.taken)::timestamp without time zone))"
"  Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 32kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1348586.56..1348590.06 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=2268.829..2268.886 rows=92 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1344864.01 rows=744510 width=12) (actual time=0.807..2084.206 rows=134893 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: ((m.taken >= sc.taken_start) AND (m.taken <= sc.taken_end) AND (sc.station_id = m.station_id))"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..12755.07 rows=1220 width=18) (actual time=0.502..521.937 rows=23 loops=1)"
"                    Join Filter: ((sec_to_gc(cube_distance((ll_to_earth((c.latitude_decimal)::double precision, (c.longitude_decimal)::double precision))::cube, (ll_to_earth((s.latitude_decimal)::double precision, (s.longitude_decimal)::double precision))::cube)) / 1000::double precision) <= 30::double precision)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using city_pkey1 on city c  (cost=0.00..2.47 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (id = 5182)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..9907.73 rows=3659 width=34) (actual time=0.014..28.937 rows=3458 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on station_category sc  (cost=0.00..970.20 rows=3659 width=14) (actual time=0.008..10.947 rows=3458 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: ((taken_start >= '1900-01-01'::date) AND (taken_end <= '1996-12-31'::date) AND (category_id = 1))"
"                          ->  Index Scan using station_pkey1 on station s  (cost=0.00..2.43 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=3458)"
"                                Index Cond: (s.id = sc.station_id)"
"                                Filter: (s.applicable AND (s.elevation >= 0) AND (s.elevation <= 3000))"
"              ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1072.27 rows=947 width=18) (actual time=6.996..63.199 rows=5865 loops=23)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on measurement m  (cost=0.00..25.00 rows=6 width=22) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=23)"
"                          Filter: (m.category_id = 1)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on measurement_001 m  (cost=20.79..1047.27 rows=941 width=18) (actual time=6.995..62.390 rows=5865 loops=23)"
"                          Recheck Cond: ((m.station_id = sc.station_id) AND (m.taken >= sc.taken_start) AND (m.taken <= sc.taken_end) AND (m.category_id = 1))"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on measurement_001_stc_idx  (cost=0.00..20.55 rows=941 width=0) (actual time=5.775..5.775 rows=5865 loops=23)"
"                                Index Cond: ((m.station_id = sc.station_id) AND (m.taken >= sc.taken_start) AND (m.taken <= sc.taken_end) AND (m.category_id = 1))"
"Total runtime: 2269.264 ms"
```

**1900 to 1997: Full Table Scan**

```
"Sort  (cost=1370192.26..1370192.76 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=86165.797..86165.809 rows=94 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: (date_part('year'::text, (m.taken)::timestamp without time zone))"
"  Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 32kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1370181.12..1370184.62 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=86165.654..86165.736 rows=94 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=4293.60..1366355.81 rows=765061 width=12) (actual time=534.786..85920.007 rows=139721 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (m.station_id = sc.station_id)"
"              Join Filter: ((m.taken >= sc.taken_start) AND (m.taken <= sc.taken_end))"
"              ->  Append  (cost=0.00..867005.80 rows=43670150 width=18) (actual time=0.009..79202.329 rows=43670079 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on measurement m  (cost=0.00..25.00 rows=6 width=22) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: (category_id = 1)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on measurement_001 m  (cost=0.00..866980.80 rows=43670144 width=18) (actual time=0.008..73312.008 rows=43670079 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: (category_id = 1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=4277.93..4277.93 rows=1253 width=18) (actual time=534.704..534.704 rows=25 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=847.87..4277.93 rows=1253 width=18) (actual time=415.837..534.682 rows=25 loops=1)"
"                          Join Filter: ((sec_to_gc(cube_distance((ll_to_earth((c.latitude_decimal)::double precision, (c.longitude_decimal)::double precision))::cube, (ll_to_earth((s.latitude_decimal)::double precision, (s.longitude_decimal)::double precision))::cube)) / 1000::double precision) <= 30::double precision)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using city_pkey1 on city c  (cost=0.00..2.47 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (id = 5182)"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=847.87..1352.07 rows=3760 width=34) (actual time=6.427..35.107 rows=3552 loops=1)"
"                                Hash Cond: (s.id = sc.station_id)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on station s  (cost=0.00..367.25 rows=7948 width=20) (actual time=0.004..23.529 rows=7949 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (applicable AND (elevation >= 0) AND (elevation <= 3000))"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=800.87..800.87 rows=3760 width=14) (actual time=6.416..6.416 rows=3552 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on station_category sc  (cost=430.29..800.87 rows=3760 width=14) (actual time=2.316..5.353 rows=3552 loops=1)"
"                                            Recheck Cond: (category_id = 1)"
"                                            Filter: ((taken_start >= '1900-01-01'::date) AND (taken_end <= '1997-12-31'::date))"
"                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on station_category_station_category_idx  (cost=0.00..429.35 rows=6376 width=0) (actual time=2.268..2.268 rows=6339 loops=1)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (category_id = 1)"
"Total runtime: 86165.936 ms"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the station ID was not sequentially distributed in the measurement tables. The solution:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX measurement_001_stc_index
  ON climate.measurement_001
  USING btree
  (station_id, taken, category_id);
ALTER TABLE climate.measurement_001 CLUSTER ON measurement_001_stc_index;
```

By forcing a `CLUSTER` on the columns, the station IDs were aligned physically on disk with the table's natural order. This gave a performance increase of an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Postgres overestimates how many stations are there in vicinity of a city 5182. It thinks there is 1220 but there's only 23.

You can two queries to force getting the stations first, like this (not tested, may need tweeking):

```
start transaction;
create temporary table s(id int);
insert into s
  select id from
    climate.city c,
    climate.station s
  where
    c.id = 5182 AND
    earth_distance(
      ll_to_earth(c.latitude_decimal,c.longitude_decimal),
      ll_to_earth(s.latitude_decimal,s.longitude_decimal)) / 1000 <= 30 AND
    s.elevation BETWEEN 0 AND 3000 AND
    s.applicable = TRUE;
analyze s;

SELECT
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken) AS year,
    avg(m.amount) AS amount
  FROM
    climate.station_category sc,
    climate.measurement m,
    s
  WHERE
    sc.category_id = 1 AND
    sc.taken_start >= '1900-01-01'::date AND
    sc.taken_end <= '1996-12-31'::date AND
    m.station_id = sc.station_id AND
    m.taken BETWEEN sc.taken_start AND sc.taken_end AND
    m.category_id = sc.category_id AND
    sc.station_id = s.id
  GROUP BY
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken)
  ORDER BY
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken);
rollback;
```

---

You can also `set enable_seqscan=off` for this query. This will force Postgres to avoid sequential scans at all cost.

Comment: On second thought I've rewritten a query to 2 queries using temporary table. This way Postgres cannot overestimate stations. Please try this and tell if it works better.

Comment: Stations are gathered in a sub-select. The sub-select was tweaked to find the bounding rectangle for the radius. This allows PostgreSQL to eliminate stations using an index, thereby needing to check only those stations that fall within the minimum bounding rectangle to see if they are within the given radius. The large performance increase came from aligning the physical model with the logical model using `CLUSTER`ed indexes.